# Expo react native, how to make a responsive clickable list with columns

Tags: react-native, expo

I have recently been learning react native and I am using expo. I want to make a responsive grid of clickable items. Similar to how an iphones main screen has a bunch of apps on it in a grid. My attemps so far have gotten me this:

[image]

For what you see in the image I am using a flat list with a fixed number of columns (hence one of the columns being cut off). The items in the list do not respond to clicks.

How should I go about making this into a responsive grid that adjusts to different phones screen sizes, have it scrollable (which it currently is) and have each item in the list respond to being pressed?

I appreciate anything pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in two ways.
1. by using ant rn design use "GRID COMPONENT"
      `<Grid
          data={data}
          columnNum={3}
          isCarousel
          onPress={(_el, index) => alert(index)}
        />`

```
**Sample** : [Vist][1]
for more [visit here][1] .
```

2. By Using "FlatList" 
      `<FlatList
           data={[{},{}]} //array of objects
           renderItem={({item}) => (
             <TouchableOpacity
               style={style.GridViewBlockStyle}
               onPress={this._handleClick.bind(this, item.link, item.text)}
             >
               <View
                 style={{
                   height: 100,
                   justifyContent: 'center',
                   alignItems: 'center',
                 }}
                >
                 {item.icon}
                   <Text style={style.GridViewInsideTextItemStyle}> {item.text} 
                   </Text>
                 )}
               </View>
             </TouchableOpacity>
           )}
           numColumns={3}
           keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
           style={{}}
         />`

   **Sample** [Visit](https://expo.io/@rajnish42413).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response!

I actually got it working overnight using <Grid>